# Блокируется фоновый поток в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность

Обрабатываю нажатие кнопки в другом потоке.Так как в нём используются другие контролы использую `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`.Но при нажатии на кнопку основной поток все равно блокируется (приложение зависает)

```
private  void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    Thread thread = new Thread(GO);
    thread.Start();
}

void GO()
{
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)delegate ()
    {

        using (EFContext _context = new EFContext())
        {
            var res = _context.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == Email.Text && x.Password == Password.Password);
            if (res != null)
            {
                MainWindow w = new MainWindow(res.Id);
                w.Show();
                this.Close();
            }
            else
            {
               IncorrectData.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Dispatcher.BeginInvoke планирует выполнение кода в GUI потоке. Т.е. вы создаете новый поток и в нем планируете выполнение кода в исходном потоке. Это бессмысленно. Вам следует обернуть в Dispatcher.BeginInvoke только ту часть кода, что непосредственно работает с GUI

Comment: @АндрейNOP если я помещаю Dispatcher прямо в FirstOrDefault вылетает exception

Comment: Помещайте в Dispatcher.BeginInvoke только блок if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нет никакого смысла оборачивать в `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` весь метод. Вы, фактически, не используете фоновой поток - вы всю работу делаете в основном потоке.

Вам нужно:

1. Получить все параметры запроса в основном потоке:

   ```
   var data = Dispatcher.Invoke(() => new { email = Email.text, password = Password.Text });
   ```
2. Выполнить запрос:

   ```
   User user;
   using (EFContext _context = new EFContext())
   {
       user = _context.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Email == data.email && x.Password == data.Password);
   }
   ```
3. Обработать результат запроса:

   ```
   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
       if (user != null) ...;
   });
   ```

---

Альтернативный вариант - вовсе не использовать явный фоновой поток, воспользовавшись асинхронным методом. Тут все нужно делать точно так же, только наоборот: шаги 1 и 3 выполняются напрямую, а шаг 2 - через `await Task.Run(() => { ... })`